# Can't access object's parameters from the other class's func

Tags: c++, oop

I have several classes.

```
class DRAW {
private:
    unsigned int back_texture;
    unsigned int hero_texture;

public:
    DRAW();
    ~DRAW();
    void start_draw();
    void draw_back();
    void draw_hero();
    void end_draw();

};
class HERO {

private:
    float x,y,w,h; //coordinates
    float hp; //health

public:
    friend class DRAW;

    HERO(float x1, float y1, float w1, float h1, float hp1);
    ~HERO();

    void set_posX(float x1);
    void set_posY(float y1);
    void set_height(float h1);
    void set_width(float w1);
    void set_health(float hp1);

    float get_posX();
    float get_posY();
    float get_height();
    float get_width();
    float get_health();

    void move(char direrion);

};
```

I have created object in the main function (**hero = new HERO()**) of my program. I'm trying to access the parameters of object hero from draw_hero() function.

```
void DRAW :: draw_hero() {

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, hero_texture);

glBegin(GL_QUADS);

glTexCoord2d(0,0); glVertex2f(hero->get_posX(),hero->get_posY());
glTexCoord2d(1,0); glVertex2f(hero->get_posX() + hero->get_width(),hero->get_posY());
glTexCoord2d(1,1); glVertex2f(hero->get_posX() + hero->get_width(),hero->get_posY() + hero -> get_height());
glTexCoord2d(0,1); glVertex2f(hero->get_posX(),hero->get_posY());
glEnd();

}
```

When I compile i het this:
    **draw.h:83:32: error: ‘hero’ was not declared in this scope**

What is wrong with it?

**ADDED:** Main looks like this :

```
int main (int argc, char* argv[] ) {

 /* DECLARATION */

SDL_Event event;

SYSTEM* system;

bool isRunning = true;

Uint8* key;

static HERO* hero;
hero = new HERO(300,300, 40, 40, 100);

DRAW* image = new DRAW;
DRAW();
.
.
.
    /* RENDERING */


    image -> start_draw();
    image -> draw_back();
    image -> end_draw();
```

Comment: The error message is complaining that your variable "hero" isn't visible in the same scope as whatever is on line 83 in draw.h. Can you show us your main function/code around line 83?

Comment: You need to have a `HERO` member for your `DRAW` class or pass a `HERO` instance to `draw_hero()`

Comment: You're entirely right, I didn't realise the opengl code was in a function there. Post your response as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare your function with an argument something like that

```
void DRAW :: draw_hero(HERO * hero) {/* rest of the code*/}
```

and pass your pointer to created object `hero` to the function when calling.

Comment: Also note the `friend` declaration which is essentially backwards. It seems the OP tried to introduce the `draw_hero()` function to the `HERO` class and then assumed that the `friend` would allow him to use fields from the `hero` object in the function...  Essentially it seems the OP got the use of `friend` backwards.

Comment: Should introduce my HERO class as friend in DRAW class?

Comment: For the way you're using it you don't need friend at all since you're only accessing public member functions.